# Bifurcation paramter in the initial condition?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, bifurcation

Consider
$u_t=u_{xx}+u(1-u^2), x\in\mathbb{R}$

with initial conditions $u_0(x)=u_0(x+\frac{2\pi}{k})$.

Now, in [this paper](http://www.math.umn.edu/~scheel/preprints/coarsening.pdf) what seems to happen is that $k$ is considered to be the bifurcation parameter and the equlibria are the periodic solutions, isn't it?  (Figure 1.1)

I am wondering about the fact that the bifurcation parameter seems to be in the initial conditions and not in the equation itself.

Is that something special or how would one handle this (I have never seen something like this).

Comment: The bifurcation parameter could be anywhere, not just initial condition. In discrete maps, it is mostly in the initial condition. But in continuous maps, it is generally a parameter in the dynamical equation. [See here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bifurcation_theory#Local_bifurcations)

Comment: Ok, so the bifurcation parameter can be in the initial conditions. But how can I draw the diagram then?

Comment: If the bifurcation parameter is a part of the system's dynamical equation, then drawing the bifurcation diagram would be a serious pain in the butt. When it is in the initial conditions, then the job is relatively easier. There are some examples and codes on wikipedia for discrete maps

Comment: Maybe I am searching wrong but can you give me an easy example for a bifurcation parameter appearing in the initial conditions and where a bifurcation diagram is plotted?

Comment: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Fractals/Iterations_of_real_numbers/r_iterations